# What does it means if I declare function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

What does it means when I in my code declare something like :
 Foo * foo();
What benefits it gives me ?
Ist not simple pointer variable as you see . 
Also 
What does it mean if I declare it in the c++ source above all methods for example :

```
// Test cpp class 
.

    #include "Foo.h"
    Foo * foo();

    Test::Test() {}
    Test::GetFooMethods()
    {
        foo()->someMethod();
    }
    …
    …
```

Comment: What does your book have to say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Foo * foo();` is a declaration to a function named `foo` which returns a pointer to a `Foo` object.  It is *not* a function pointer.

The code `Foo()->someMethod();`  is probably a typo.  You probably meant `foo()->someMethod();`.  In this case, the code calls `foo()` which as stated above returns a pointer to a `Foo` object, and then you call the `Foo::someMethod()` method through that pointer.

If in fact you did mean `Foo()->someMethod();` things get a little crazy.  What this means is first a `Foo` object is default initialized on the stack.  Then `Foo::operator->()` is called, returning some object which has a method named `someMethod()`, and that function is called.  See why I guess that it was a typo? :)

EDIT:

To answer the last question in your post, when you declare a function without defining it, you are telling the compiler, "I've got a function named foo that takes no parameters and returns a pointer to a Foo, but I'm not going to tell you how that function is implemented yet."  This allows you to write code that uses that function and the compiler will be happy.  The linker however will be quite grumpy with you if you do not someplace provide a definition for this function.

Comment: @James:  ty, good explanation what a function pointer really would look like.

Comment: fixed the type, so its like Foo* foo = new Foo()?

Answer (score 7):

```
Foo * foo();
```

This is not a function pointer.  This is a declaration of a function named `foo` that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to a `Foo`.

A pointer to a function of this type would look like:

```
Foo* (*foo_ptr)() = foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like

```
int getX();
```

is a declaration of a function that returns an int, so too

```
Foo * foo();
```

is a declaration of a function that returns a Foo pointer;

Answer (score 1):

> What does it means when I in my code
>   declare something like : Foo * foo();

```
Foo * foo();
```

Very tough to say without knowing what is Foo.

If Foo is a type e.g. `struct Foo{};`, then this declares a function named 'foo' which returns a pointer to some type called Foo. This looks to be the case in your post based on your usage subsequently (and also the title of the post).

If Foo is a #define e.g. `#define Foo 1`, then this is not a declaration but an expression statement which multiplies 1 by the return value of 'foo' in case operator * is defined for the types of the operands involved.

> What benefits it gives me ?

Tough to say again without knowing what Foo is.

> Also What does it mean if I declare it
>   in the c++ source above all methods

Declaring 'foo' (if it is indeed a declaration) as high as possible in the translation unit means larger the tentative scope of the name 'foo'.

```
void f1(){g();} // not OK, 'g' not known

void f(){}

void g(){f();}  // OK, f() is known
```

BTW, does `Foo` (caps F) have an overloaded operator `->`?

Comment: +1 for an illustration of the crazy stuff that happens when people use macros.